# Vanilla JS addEventListener change on select fires only once

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am using an ecommerce system where I dont have access to HTML code or anything but I can add custom JS code to alter some things and CSS.
I need to edit the shipping info text which is right to Doba dodania text.
My issue is that the event fires only once and not on every select change event.
Can someone help me why it is firing only once? It was needed to add SetTimeOut too.
Please check the page and console logs here:
https://www.privlacuj.sk/Hacik-Offset-Light-Class-AT-21-cena-za-1ks-d2336_1013278452.htm

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function change_doba_dodania() {
var c757_counter = document.querySelectorAll(".c757").length;
var variant = document.querySelectorAll(".c755.variant").length;
var out_of_stock = document.querySelectorAll(".c757.out-of-stock").length;
console.log(c757_counter);
console.log(variant);
console.log(out_of_stock);

if (out_of_stock > 0) {
    console.log("Nincs raktaron");
}

if ( ( c757_counter >= 2 ) && ( out_of_stock == 0 ) ){
    var dd_text = document.getElementsByClassName("c757")[1].innerHTML;
    console.log(dd_text);
    var dd_text_array = dd_text.split(" ");
    var dd_final = dd_text_array.filter(String);
    console.log(dd_final);

    if (dd_final[2] == "zajtra") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("c757")[1].innerHTML = dd_final[6] + " " + dd_final[7] + " " + dd_final[8] + " " + dd_final[9] + " " + dd_final[10] + " a Vaša zásielka bude expedovaná už " + dd_final[2];
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("c757")[1].innerHTML = dd_final[6] + " " + dd_final[7] + " " + dd_final[8] + " - " + dd_final[9] + " a Vaša zásielka bude expedovaná už " + dd_final[2];
    }
}
}



window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
change_doba_dodania();
});

var variant = document.querySelectorAll(".c755.variant").length;

if (variant > 0){
document.querySelector('.c757 select').addEventListener('change', function() 
{setTimeout(change_doba_dodania, 1500)});

document.querySelector('.c757 select').addEventListener('change',() => 
    setTimeout(console.log, 1000, "Changed")
) 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think the issue is in the way you're getting `variant` value(s), since you're using `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: With variant I just check that the product is variable or not. The change event works and it is fired but only once. I cant create a minimal version because its tied to the ecommerce system which my client use. If I create a blank HTML with addEventListener it works just fine.
https://lifetime-licensz.hu/ar.html

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question, your problem is `querySelector`.

`querySelector` only selects the first element with the given class name. If you want to select all the elements with the given class name, you should use `querySelectorAll`.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".c757 select").forEach(select => {
    select.addEventListener(...)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just added: document.querySelectorAll(".c757 select").forEach(select => {
    select.addEventListener('change',() => 
        setTimeout(console.log, 1000, "Changed")
    ) 
})
But its not working.

Comment: This would solve the issue if I would have more select boxes with the same class I assume. But my issue is that the event is not fired more than once. So if I choose an option once its ok but after that if I choose another option from the select box there is not event fired. But by defaulat addEventListerener should fire every time when you change the select box value.

Comment: Oh sorry i got your question wrong but your assumption is right. I will try.